# Different Layouts inside CardsWithList cardslib Library

Tags: android, cardslib

Im using [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) inside my project
Is it possible to inflate another Layouts inside the CardsWithList? I want to add a somekind of footer at the end which would be clickable to open another fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use different layouts for each row in `CardWithList`, you can't do it.

If you want to use a custom layout for the

As other cards you can use a custom inner layout instead of the [default layout](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/library-core/src/main/res/layout/native_inner_base_main_cardwithlist.xml).
You can set it in your constructor for example:

```
public WeatherCard(Context context) {
    super(context,R.layout.carddemo_extras_inner_base_main_cardwithlist);
}
```

Your layout **have to provide** an element with `

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.prototypes.LinearListView
        android:id="@+id/card_inner_base_main_cardwithlist"
    />
```

Also you can add other elements inside you layout.
In this case you have to set them with the method
`setupInnerViewElements`. In this case it is very important to call the super method.

```
 @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {
        //It is very important call the super method!!
        super.setupInnerViewElements(parent, view);

        //Your elements
    }
```

You can find more [info here:](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDWITHLIST.md#using-a-custom-inner-layout)

Comment: Yea I've already inflated the custom layout and it works fine :). I'm not sure I understand what  ou mean by adding other elements inside my layout? can you explain more?

Comment: If you have a button for example use that method to set an OnClickListener